# Installed Ipython3 but the version still says 1.2.1

Tags: python, ipython

The python version I have is 3.4.3. I tried using the Ipython3 qtconsole but same issue

Comment: Could you give more info on which version of what you see?

Comment: when I type ipython3 in the terminal it says
python 3.4.3 and ipython 1.2.1

Comment: That's the version of ipython. ipython is a separate project and its versions are not aligned with python versions. You may consider upgrading ipython, 1.2.1 seems quiet old.

Comment: so that's what I tried. But it tells me I've got the most up to date one. I typed sudo apt-get install ipython3

Comment: From version 4.0.0 the project has been split, and parts of it are now called "jupyter" (for better integration with other tools/languages likr Julia and R). Maybe the package name has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

The `ipython3` executable just means "IPython for Python 3", it doesn't have any relationship to the version of IPython itself. IPython 1.2.1 is still the current version that ships with some Linux distros, so if you installed with `apt-get` or `yum`, this is likely the reason. If you want a more recent version, you can install with `pip`:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade ipython
```

If `pip list` shows a recent version of IPython, but starting `ipython` still shows an old version, it could be because `setuptools` has corrupted your path via a file called `easy-install.pth`. Look for these files on your system, and check if there are any `/usr/lib/python3.4/dist-packages` in there. If so, remove those lines because it's wrong for that path to be included in the file.

You may also remove the outdated IPython with

```
apt-get remove ipython
```